# ScrollSpy with script added ids

Tags: javascript, scrollspy

First of all I'm sorry if I repeat anything that has been posted elsewhere. I've been looking into solutions other people have found for their problems and I've implemented (or so I think) the things they found but the site I'm working on still doesn't do what it's supposed to.

So, the site I'm working on is http://www.vinck-interieur.be/?lang=en.
What's supposed to happen is that when scrolling down or up, visitors see where they are in the sidebar menu. ScrollSpy seemed the best option to do this but it hasn't been working since I've put it in my code.
I invite you to go into the code that I've put in my website but here's the main idea

```
<body id="top" <?php body_class(); ?> data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navigation-bar">
    <header id="header" class="...">
        <div class="bottom-head">
            <nav id="access" role="navigation" class="navigation-bar>
                <div class="menu-container loaded">
                    <ul id="menu-main-menu-en" class="top-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-672" class="menu-item menu-item-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-672 normal-menu">
                            <a href="#top"><span>home</span></a>
                        </li>
                        ...
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="mid" class="...">
        <article id="content" class="clearfix">
            <div id="col-mask">
                <div id="post-632" class="...">
                    <div class="real-content">
                        <div class="a13_row_container lift-up" style="...">...</div>
                        <div class="a13_row_container a13_full_row a13_full_content" style="...">...</div>
                        <div class="a13_row_container lift-up" style="...">...</div>
                        <div class="a13_row_container a13_full_row a13_full_content" style="...">...</div>
                        <div class="a13_row_container lift-up" style="...">...</div>
                        <div class="a13_row_container a13_full_row a13_full_content" style="...">...</div>
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

After my footer I first add jQuery, then call for Bootstrap and then use JS to add certain IDs to every second element with a class of "a13_full-row":

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("a13_full-row");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i+=2) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                rows[i].setAttribute("id", "home");
                break;
            case 2:
                rows[i].setAttribute("id", "ontwerp");
                break;
            case 4:
                rows[i].setAttribute("id", "project");
                break;
            case 6:
                rows[i].setAttribute("id", "advies");
                break;
            case 8:
                rows[i].setAttribute("id", "portfolio");
                break;
            case 10:
                rows[i].setAttribute("id", "contact");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I look at the website code this all happens. 
 Then I refresh scroll spy using:

```
<script>
jQuery('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
            if(jQuery(this).scrollspy('refresh')) {
                console.log("yay");
            }
        });
<script>
```

I get the log message so it should have been refreshed. 
And according to everything I've found this should work. 
I've added "data-spy" and "data-target" to the body so I don't need to imply a scroll bar.
I've refreshed scroll spy so it get's updated to the script added IDs.
...
But it doesn't.
Can anyone help me?

If any more code is required I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up getting rid of ScrollSpy and using JQuery/JavaScript for a custom solution. I use the next deactivate function to remove 'active' from class of all the items in my menu

function deactivate() {
        var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item'); // All

in side menu

```
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        var menuLinks = menuItems[i].childNodes; // All <a> in <li> in side menu
        var tempClass = document.getElementById(menuItems[i].id).className.replace(/active/gi, ''); // replace 'active' by ''
        menuItems[i].className = tempClass;
    }
}
```

Call an unnamed function every time the user scrolls:

```
jQuery(document).on('scroll',function() {
```

Use 'scrollTop()' to get the offset of what you view to the top of the page.
Use 'offsetTop' to get the offset of that object to the top of the page.

```
    var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop(), // Position on the page of the top of your window (page offset)
    homeOffset = document.getElementById("home").offsetTop, // The offset this element has on the page compared to the top (object offset)
    ontwerpOffset = document.getElementById("ontwerp").offsetTop,
    projectOffset = document.getElementById("project").offsetTop,
    adviesOffset = document.getElementById("advies").offsetTop,
    portfolioOffset = document.getElementById("portfolio").offsetTop,
    contactOffset = document.getElementById("contact").offsetTop,
```

Get the distance the object/anchor is from the top of what you're viewing and make it an absolute value using 'Math.abs()'.

```
    distHome = Math.abs((homeOffset - scrollTop)), // Absolute value(object offset - page offset)
    distOntwerp = Math.abs((ontwerpOffset - scrollTop)),
    distProject = Math.abs((projectOffset - scrollTop)),
    distAdvies = Math.abs((adviesOffset - scrollTop)),
    distPortfolio = Math.abs((portfolioOffset - scrollTop)),
    distContact = Math.abs((contactOffset - scrollTop));
```

Log the second one to check.

```
    console.log("ontwerp: " +distOntwerp);
```

Get the value of the smallest of all the offsets and log it to check

```
    var minOffset = Math.min(distHome, distOntwerp, distProject, distAdvies, distPortfolio, distContact); // The smallest value of them all
    console.log("min: " + minOffset);
```

'switch' this minimum to a 'case' of every anchor (I have a multi language site but didn't want to repeat myself to much so I use 'try catch' for the right menu-item in each language

```
    switch (minOffset) {
        case distHome:
            deactivate();
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-671").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-672").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-673").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            break;
        case distOntwerp:
            deactivate();
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-54").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-657").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-663").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            break;
        case distProject:
            deactivate();
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-59").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-658").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-664").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            break;
        case distAdvies:
            deactivate();
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-56").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-659").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-665").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            break;
        case distPortfolio:
            deactivate();
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-57").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-660").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-666").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            break;
        case distContact:
            deactivate();
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-58").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-661").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            try{
                document.getElementById("menu-item-667").className += ' active';
            } catch(e) {}
            break;

    }

});
```